# How can you add users to wordpress from outside the wordpress environment programmatically

Tags: wordpress, bulkinsert

I'm writing a script to import data into wordpress from a text file.

The data needs to access posts, users, custom fields and post meta data.

To import it, I'm looking up the author in the user table, fetching the ID if it exists (and can't generate one if it doesn't), then inserting the post data, adding the post meta and fetching remote images to insert and add those as post meta data as well.

I'm replicating data from an existing site the client owns in ASP.net and pulling it into wordpress for them, however, I can't quite work out how to programmatically add the user.  My intention was do this without calling a public page with a wordpress function, but simply to try to replicate the appropriate SQL used.

Could someone direct me to the functions needed that perform the queries to insert a new user?

Thanks,

Comment: See `wp_insert_user();` its in /wp-includes/user.php

(http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user)

Comment: Hi, sorry, I meant to say - how do you do this 'outside' wordpress, not inside.  The above function only works inside wordpress and doesn't seem to have the full query.  I'm still digging :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a new user. (assuming the new database uses the standard table prefix of 'wp_')

```
INSERT INTO
  wp_users
    (user_login, 
     user_pass, 
     user_nicename, 
     user_email, 
     user_url, 
     user_status, 
     display_name, 
     user_registered)
  VALUES
    ('$user_login', 
     '$user_pass', 
     '$user_nicename', 
     '$user_email', 
     '$user_url', 
     '$user_status', 
     '$display_name', 
     NOW())
```

Get the insert id then set the users role & level e.g. Subscriber

```
$capabilities = serialize(array('subscriber'));

INSERT INTO
  wp_usermeta
  (user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES
  ('$insert_id', 'wp_capabilities', '$capabilities')

INSERT INTO
  wp_usermeta
  (user_id, meta_key, meta_value)
VALUES
  ('$insert_id', 'wp_user_level', '0')
```

Comment: Hi tkelly, thank you! - Any idea how to set the $user_pass value to be of the same style as used in wordpress by default?  This gets me to working through - thank you!

Comment: WordPress uses PHPass by default but a regular md5 hash will also work just fine